# SVN create a new repository from another repository's folder

Tags: svn

I created an svn repository on my other Linux installation. I'm a newbie and served the whole Netbeans project folder in that repo. I now decided to keep source files in a directory and keep the SVN repository root in another path. The problem is I don't know / can't imagine how to add the sources folder to a new repository **by not disrupting its current revision number.** Let me demonstrate it:

old repo:

`/home/username/Desktop/SVN` --> repository path

`/home/username/NetbeansProjects/prj` --> imported by "svn import ..." and developed further

new repo (the one I want to accomplish on my new Linux installation):

`/home/username/Desktop/SVN/prj` --> repository path

`/home/username/Desktop/KOD/prj` --> I want to serve old repo's /home/username/NetbeansProjects/prj/src/prj/* from this path (which is @ rev 31)

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Don't edit the word "Solved" into the title. Mark the correct answer, this is a Q&A site, **not a forum**. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dump the old repo into a file and then import the file into the new repo:

```
svnadmin dump /home/username/Desktop/SVN > svn.dump

svnadmin load /home/username/Desktop/SVN/prj < svn.dump
```

You can also keep your dump file as a backup is something goes wrong. You can also just copy the directory if you will use the same version of SVN in both servers. SVN Dump is version independent.

Comment: I am trying to get the files _only_ under `/home/username/NetbeansProjects/prj/src/prj/*`.

Comment: As it seems, I will have to go through all my understanding of svn. Thanks, ghm1014.

Comment: @kRm After you import the dump, you can always remove resources from the repo that you don't need. And `svn` is certainly an application where understanding is key ;).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. I've googled really a lot and found out there are no tools able to rename files directly in dump and there's no way to make `svnadmin load` to rename files.
Because I have a small repo I did that manually with vim: just replaced
`Node-path: trunk/very/log/path/to/project/directory` to `Node-path: trunk/directory`

P.S. my dump is SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2